# Showing that the equation $x_i - \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}x_j = b_i$ has a unique solution.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, banach-spaces

**Exercise :**

> Consider the infinite-dimensional system of equations :
>   $$x_i - \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}x_j = b_i, \quad i=1,2,3,\dots$$
>   We suppose that $b=(b_1,b_2,\dots) \in \ell^\infty$ and that it exists $0<\theta<1$ such that :
>   $$\sup_i \sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|\leq \theta$$
>   Show that the system of equations given has a unique solution $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots) \in \ell^\infty$.

**Attempt :**

In previous exercises and lessons, I have proved the following lemma :

> Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T \in B(X)$ with $\|T\| \leq \theta < 1$. Then, if $y \in X$, the equation $x = y + Tx$ has a unique solution $x \in X$.

My initial idea is to work over manipulating the exercise to reach the statements of the lemma above.

The equation for the infinite-dimensional system of equations given, can be rewritten as :

$$x_i - \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}x_j = b_i \Rightarrow x = b + Tx$$

where $x = (x_1,x_2,\dots)$ and $T$ be an operator, such that :

$$Tx = \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}x_j$$

Now, I observe that $\ell^\infty$ is a Banach space and since $b \in \ell^\infty$ then $x - Tx \in \ell^\infty$ which means that $x \in \ell^\infty$ and $T$ is an operator defined over $\ell^\infty$.

Now, I need to prove that $T \in B(\ell^\infty)$, which means that $T$ is a bounded linear operator $T : \ell^\infty \to \ell^\infty$ and that $\|T\| < 1$.

For the case of linearity, let $x,y \in \ell^\infty$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. Then, it is

$$T(\lambda x + y) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}(\lambda x_j + y_j) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \lambda a_{ij} x_j + \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}y_j$$

$$=$$

$$\lambda \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}x_j + \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}y_j = \lambda T x + Ty$$

which proves that $T$ is a linear operator.

Now, for the case of $T$ being bounded :

$$\|Tx\|_\infty = \bigg\|\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}x_j \bigg\|_\infty \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty \|a_{ij}x_j\|_\infty \leq \sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}| \|x\|_\infty$$

But, it is

$$\sup_i \sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|\leq \theta < 1$$

thus, by combining the two last results above, we get :

$$\|Tx\|_\infty \leq \theta \|x\|_\infty$$

which proves that $T$ is a bounded linear operator $T \in B(\ell^\infty)$ and thus the equation we transformed has a unique solution $x \in \ell^\infty$ which means that the initial infinite-dimensional system of equations has a unique solution $x=(x_1,x2,\dots) \in \ell^\infty$.

**Question :** Is my approach correct and rigorous enough ? Any recommendations on what I can improve or any mistakes ? I would appreciate any input or approvement of my approach.

Comment: You are right. Your argument contains every necessary element.